# recursively delete a specific directory for each user in C:\Users

Tags: powershell, user-folders, recursive, files-folders

Would like to use powershell to loop through all `C:\Users\*` and delete all contents of a subdirectory...
Some users, but not all, use an app that creates cache files at:
`C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\SomeApplication\CacheFiles`

I'm just not sure how to use /*/ to go to all the user dirs and continue if the CacheFiles directory doesn't exist or if it's empty...
Do we need to get all `C:\Users\` store it in an array and then pass that plus the rest of the path? Or Can we simply just say for all "Dirs" in `C:\Users\*` delete rest of path...?

I don't know if I'm making this harder than it needs to be...this is what I have:

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\SomeApplication\CacheFiles -Include *.* -File -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}`

Comment: so ... what is not working? that looks like it would get all the files in the designated dir for all your users.

Comment: Yes, it actually did work!

Comment: kool! glad to know your code worked as needed ... [*grin*]